# Modify form value after submit in symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have form like this :

1. name (required).
2. slug (required).

`slug` is required in back end but user is allowed to leave it blank in form field ( if user leave slug blank, it will use `name` as the input instead ).

I have tried with `Event form listener` but it said **You cannot change value of submitted form**. I tried with `Data transformers` like this :

```
    public function reverseTransform($slug)
{
    if ($slug) {
        return $slug;
    } else {
        return $this->builder->get('name')->getData();
    }
}
```

`return $this->builder->get('name')->getData();` always return null. So I tried like this:

```
public function reverseTransform($slug)
{
    if ($slug) {
        return $slug;
    } else {
        return $_POST['category']['name'];
    }
}
```

it works but I think it against the framework. How I can done this with right way?

Comment: Why not add a doctrine listener before storing the data? I guess that the $slug requirement is a database restriction, then why not using a simple "prePersist" with doctrine. I think that the SF data transformer are related to just one field, and symfony call it when try to normalize the form data into the model. Probably it will return null because the slug is called before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible way is to set via request class like this:

**Array form** `<input name="tag['slug']"...>`:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $postData = $request->request->get('tag'); 
    $slug = ($postData['slug']) ? $postData['slug'] : $postData['name'];
    $request->request->set('tag', array_merge($postData,['slug' => $slug]));
    .......
```

**Common form** `<input name="slug"...>`:

```
$request->request->set('slug', 'your value');
```

I think this is the best way because if you are using `dml-filter-bundle` you don't need to filter your input in your controller like this again:

```
$this->get('dms.filter')->filterEntity($entity);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it in the controller

```
    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // get the data sent from your form
        $data = $form->getData();
        $slug = $data->getSlug();


        // if no slug manually hydrate the $formObject
        if(!$slug)
        {
            $formObject->setSlug($data->getName());
        }

        $em->persist($formObject);
        $em->flush();

        return ....
      }
  }
```

Comment: is this the best way? I know I can do this but if I do this way I need to filter it manually using `dms-filter`. but if this is the right way hmmm I think I haven't any choice left.

Comment: it's a quite clean way... can't tell if the best

Comment: finally, I choose this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a function to keep the code at one place then you should also not work with Request data.
In the form action you call that function including the name variable.

```
public function reverseTransform($name, $slug)
{
    if (!empty($slug)) {
        return $slug;
    } else {
        return $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not common function. It's a class that implemented `DataTransformerInterface` so I can't do it that way.